# Insertion of an data in an XML using Basex

Tags: xquery, basex, xml-database, xquery-update

I am storing two XML documents, namely hospital and office, in BaseX.

The following is the office xml:

```
<Staff>
    <Employee Name="Brian">
        <Personal>
            <SSN> 666-66-6666 </SSN>
        </Personal>
        <StaffInfo>
            <Position> Doctor </Position>
            <AccountableTo> David </AccountableTo>
        </StaffInfo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee Name="David">
        <Personal>
            <SSN> 555-55-5555 </SSN>
        </Personal>
        <StaffInfo>
            <Position> Doctor </Position>
            <AccountableTo />
        </StaffInfo>
    </Employee>
</Staff>
```

In this XML I want to add one or more employees. How can I add elements using BaseX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XQuery has an update facility, an [official W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/), called XQuery Update to change the document structure.

You can use updates like so:

Given you have created a database employees, with the commmand:

`CREATE DB office /path/to/office.xml`

Now you may use the XQuery Update facility and run the following query:

```
let $up := <Employee Name="Joe">
    <Personal>
      <SSN>666-66-1234</SSN>
    </Personal>
    <StaffInfo>
      <Position>Doctor</Position>
      <AccountableTo>Jeff</AccountableTo>
    </StaffInfo>
  </Employee>

  return
insert node $up as last into doc('office')/Staff
```

This will ad the node referenced by `$up` at the last position in your database `staff`

The [BaseX Documentation Wiki](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates) contains more information on updates:

There is a good tutorial, [XQuery Update for the impatient](http://www.xmlmind.com/tutorials/XQueryUpdate/index.html) provided by xmlmind.com.

Sure enough you can use the APIs to issue these queries, for a start I'd suggest you stick with GUI, so you can see results directly.

Hope this helped, feel free to ask for more information; either here or on the official [BaseX Mailing List](https://mailman.uni-konstanz.de/mailman/listinfo/basex-talk).

Comment: Thanks for the information let me try and implement with the help of the information provided by Michael,..