# Insert an element as a child Element in existing XML using Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I am new to Xquery.
I am working on something where I need to insert a new XML element into existing XML.

Ex:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

The above xml needs to be updated by adding a new Element address.

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    <address>Address</address>
</note>
```

This needs to be done using XQuery.

I refered to [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407743/insertion-of-an-data-in-an-xml-using-basex)

Please Advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An XQuery 1.0 solution would be to use a recursive typeswitch function:

```
declare function local:insert-address($nodes as node()*)
{
 for $node in $nodes
 return 
    typeswitch($node)
        case element(note)
            return 
                element { name($node) } {
                    $node/@*, 
                    local:insert-address($node/node()),
                    element address { "Address" }
                }
        case element()
            return 
                element { name($node) } {
                    $node/@*, 
                    local:insert-address($node/node())
                }
        default 
            return $node
};

let $doc := 
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>

return 
  local:insert-address($doc)
```

Depending on what XQuery engine you are using, there may be more simple solutions if your processor supports [XQuery Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/) like Alexander Petrov's answer, or custom functions such as MarkLogic's [xdmp:node-insert-child()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-insert-child).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
copy $note :=
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

modify (insert node <address>Address</address> into $note)

return $note
```